# How does Spring detect a session?

Tags: java, spring, session

Here is how i think session detection works in a standard way.

1. The user authenticates
2. The backend generates a sessioncookie
3. The backend sends the cookie in response to the client
4. The user sends back the cookie with every new request

And Spring detects the right session by identifying the cookie.

Here is my problem:
I am currently working on a javafx client and use springs own kind of RMI via `AuthenticationSimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor` to make my authentification. It works fine, but i save some data in session-scoped beans. I fill these beans in the first request and expect my data to still be there at the second request. But with every request i get a new (empty) session-scoped bean.

I guess spring does not recognize the session and opens a new one. Thats why i get new session-scoped beans with every request.

`AuthenticationSimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor` does not send any cookie but it sends username and password as http-basic-authentification with every request. So there is plenty of Information left to still find the Session and inject the correct session-scoped Beans. Why does not spring use username and password to identify a session?

Comment: Backend has to generate session ID (JSESSIONID) - please check your headers if it does.

Comment: The servlet container (e.g. Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss) does it.